# PHP Alternative text for SWITCH case

Tags: php, html, css, switch-statement

I am just trying to add HTML code into PHP code,My problem is that i just wanted to display div using switch case in php and that div is  actually made "display:none" using inline property of CSS by me,Below is my SWITCH case code

```
<?php switch ($sem): 
      case 1: ?>
            ok.....
     <?php break; ?>

     <?php case 2: ?>
              <style type='text/css'>
                #sem1{
                    display:block;
                }
                </style>    

    <?php break; ?>   

<?php endswitch ?>
```

This Code not displaying block.
Thank you

Comment: For me your code is  working, what is the value you defined for $sem,

Comment: Please share your HTML Code

Comment: Code is working but output is characters like ?>

Comment: what about did u get??

Comment: @Muthusamy Sorry i wanted div block to display

Comment: <?php 
$sem=2;
switch ($sem): 
      case 1: ?>
            ok.....
     <?php break; ?>

     <?php case 2: ?>
              <style type='text/css'>
                #sem1{
                    display:none;
                }
                </style>    

    <?php break; ?>   

<?php endswitch ?>


<p id="sem1"> test for love</p>

Comment: @Muthusamy here sem1 is my div id.

Comment: yes, it will work

Comment: Please add a "! important" in the your style. and check it

Comment: @Muthusamy where please give me specific code i know that my actual problem is in syntax of style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <?php 
  $sem=2;
  switch ($sem): 
        case 1: ?>
              ok.....
       <?php break; ?>

       <?php case 2: ?>
                <style type='text/css'>
                  #sem1{
                      display:block !important;
                  }
                  </style>    

      <?php break; ?>   

  <?php endswitch ?>


  <div id="sem1" style="display:none;"> test for love</div>
```

Comment: I will.. i am just working on my college project.If any dout arises i will definitely contact you.

Comment: One more problem i am facing that  i'am using WAMP ,In one html form i set one field value  as not null by using phpMyadmin (By Unchecking  Null button) But it taking Null value